# Orthogonal projection theorem in case of incomplete space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Prove that every incomplete inner product space $H$ has a closed vector subspace $H_0$ such that $H≠H_0⊕H_0^\perp$.

I can't come up with a universal construction of such a subspace for any incomplete inner product space. Maybe we can somehow use here fact that there a Coushy sequense that doesn't converge to the element of this space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $H$ is not complete, and let $\hat{H}$ be the completion of $H$. Choose $\hat{x}\in \hat{H}\setminus H$. Let $H_0=\{ x \in H : \langle x,\hat{x}\rangle_{\hat{H}} = 0 \}$. $H_0$ is closed in $H$ and $H_0 \ne H$ because $H$ is dense in $\hat{H}$ and $\hat{x}\ne 0$. Furthermore,
$          H_0^{\perp_{H}}=\{ x \in H : x\perp H_0 \} = \{0\}.
$
So $H_0 \oplus H_0^{\perp_{H}} =H_0\oplus\{0\}\ne H$.